# How fast can a 16 core threadripper rescan your monero address for an updated balance?

Tags: blockchain, balance

Does anyone know how fast a 16 core process threadripper rescan the monero blockchain for an updated balance for an address? Currently for a 2 core processor it takes a few hours for me.

I'm basically looking for a way to scan monero addresses the fastest way possible. And yes I have the keys to these addresses.